# Internet explorer doing funny things with my website

Tags: html, css

Just wondering if someone can help me figure out why my menu is doing this in IE but none of the other browsers...

This is the code I have in my css sheet.. I'm not up to speed with css/html so I have no idea whats going on here.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*===== header =====*/
header nav {
    float:right;
}
        header nav ul li {
            float:left;
        }
            header nav ul li a {
                font-size:22px;
                color:#fff;
                height:67px;
                line-height:67px;
                text-decoration:none;
                width:101px;
                text-align:center;
                float:left;
                background:#433b8f;
                background-image: gradient(top, #383282, #484095); /* FF3.6 */
                background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #383282, #484095); /* FF3.6 */
                background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #383282),color-stop(1, #484095)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
        filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#383282', EndColorStr='#484095'); /* IE6,IE7 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#383282', EndColorStr='#484095')"; /* IE8 */
        }
        header nav ul li a.current, header nav ul li a:hover {
            padding-bottom:5px;
        }

        header nav ul li:nth-of-type(2) a {
            background:#0184cd;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #017bc8, #018ed3); /* FF3.6 */
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #017bc8),color-stop(1, #018ed3)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#017bc8', EndColorStr='#018ed3'); /* IE6,IE7 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#017bc8', EndColorStr='#018ed3')"; /* IE8 */
        }
        header nav ul li:nth-of-type(3) a {
            background:#7cbc19;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #73b515, #86c31d); /* FF3.6 */
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #73b515),color-stop(1, #86c31d)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#73b515', EndColorStr='#86c31d'); /* IE6,IE7 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#73b515', EndColorStr='#86c31d')"; /* IE8 */
        }
        header nav ul li:nth-of-type(4) a {
            background:#ffbc00;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb500, #ffc300); /* FF3.6 */
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #ffb500),color-stop(1, #ffc300)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffb500', EndColorStr='#ffc300'); /* IE6,IE7 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffb500', EndColorStr='#ffc300')"; /* IE8 */
        }
        header nav ul li:nth-of-type(5) a {
            background:#f07502;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee6c01, #f27f02); /* FF3.6 */
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #ee6c01),color-stop(1, #f27f02)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ee6c01', EndColorStr='#f27f02'); /* IE6,IE7 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ee6c01', EndColorStr='#f27f02')"; /* IE8 */
        }
        header nav ul li:nth-of-type(6) a {
            background:#d00110;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d00110, #da0116); /* FF3.6 */
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #d00110),color-stop(1, #da0116)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#d00110', EndColorStr='#da0116'); /* IE6,IE7 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#d00110', EndColorStr='#da0116')"; /* IE8 */
        }
```

This is how I am setting the menu up in the page

```
<!-- header -->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="60" alt="Smith Screenprint">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
```

its a website I'm developing for my mum :P this is the address so you can have a look at what its doing in IE
[www.smithscreenprint.co.nz](http://www.smithscreenprint.co.nz)

Comment: I like how you're using CSS selectors that are only supported in IE9 to apply styles for IE6, 7, and 8.

Comment: lol. the site is based off a template so I didn't know that :P to be fair if I could just ignore IE all together I would. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that your problem is that your menu items are not receiving any background in IE versions 6, 7, and 8. This is because the `:nth-of-type()` selector is not supported in these browsers (only in IE9) and thus those entire rules are being *ignored* by those browsers. You're trying to apply background rules for older browsers that can't read the selector they're under.

If you really need backwards compatibility in IE, you're going to have to go the old-fashioned way and specify `id="menu-one"`, `id="menu-two"`, and so on (or something similar) for your menu items.

Comment: okay cool that makes sense.. I'll start doing some reading.. do you think it might just be easier to ignore anything other than IE9? just put a little warning label at the bottom of my site?

Comment: I would recommend putting a *default* background style that applies to all the menu items, then if you want them different colors or whatever you can override them with your existing styles. That way in older browsers it will still look nice, just all the same color, and in newer browsers they will change colors as desired. Your best bet is designing fall-backs for the older browsers and making the newer browsers look pretty how you want them.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what version of IE as well as what "Internet explorer doing funny things with my website" means.

I checked in IE8 and it looked okay.  I assume your problem is in IE7.

IE has poor [:nth-of-type()](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) support.  Although, it looks like you're using Dean Edwards' IE9 to get around this.

Try replacing this:

```
header nav {
    float:right;
}
```

With this:

```
header img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: okay checked it at work on IE 6&7 the menu in the top right drops down about 100px almost into the content area for some reason. IE8 is now displaying perfectly but IE9 dose not want to show any of my headers or menus... all of which are using cufon fonts... so not really sure what to do here.

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested?  I tested a simplified version with IE7 and IE8 and it worked.

Comment: sorry have not tried yet will do when I get home tonight and will let you know how it goes.